# Let Y be non empty subset of R which is bounded above and y = supY then show that y $ \in Y \cup$ Y'.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let Y be non empty subset of R which is bounded above and y $=$ supY then show that y $ \in Y \cup$ Y', where Y' is set of limit points of Y

Now sup exists by lub property. If sup belongs to set Y then i am done. if not then there exists an element a $\in$ Y such that $a > y- \epsilon$. so a $\in$ $(y-\epsilon, y + \epsilon$ ) for any spsilon. So neighbourhood of y has a element a. So it is limit point.

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: If $Y$ is a non empty subset of $\Bbb R$ then I assume that the order relation is $\le$ and not $\subseteq$, so how is possible that $y\in \sup(Y)$ if $\sup(Y)$ is a number???

Comment: As **Masacroso** pointed out, $\sup Y$ is not a set, so $y\in\sup Y$ makes no sense. The correct theorem is that if $y\color{red}=\sup Y$, then $y\in Y\cup Y'$; your argument is a correct proof of this statement.

Comment: Well, technically, every real number is a set... But of course the remarks in the pair of comments above fully stand.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How do i write this in terms of metric space and neighbourhoods

Comment: @J.Deff: I’m not sure what you mean: $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$ *is* the $\epsilon$-nbhd of $y$ when $\Bbb R$ is given the usual metric.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i mean any neighbourhood of y has non empty intersection with Y so y is a limit point

Comment: @J.Deff: Every open nbhd of $y$ contains an open nbhd of the form $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$, and each of those has non-empty intersecton with $Y$, so every open nbhd of $y$ has non-empty intersection with $Y$. The sets $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon>0$ form a local base at $y$.